# Can the "Android Library Update" phase, somehow be sped up?

Tags: android

Eclipse Galileo,
ca 20 Android projects, with many dependencies between projects
(util, testutils, one testproject for each library and app, whitelabelling etc)

When starting Eclipse the following is displayed in the progressbar:
"Update SVN Cache", - decent speed
"Android Library Update", - SLOW, with loads of network access
"Building workspace" - decent speed

**Can the "Android Library Update" phase, somehow be sped up ?**

**Update 2011-06-14**
I'm now running Eclipse Helios, Ubuntu 32-bit 10.0.4 vbox guest on Win7 , Android SDK all fully patched as of 2011-06-14.
The same issue remains, "Android Library Update" is slow, BUT now the CPU is 100% with NO network traffic.
Sooo... JVM tweaking may work, or running Ubuntu 64-bit 10.0.4 vbox guest on Win7 host with "apt-get install ia32-libs" as an alternative. No time to investigate either of those options right now though.

Comment: can you  post your eclipse.ini file contents it might be how you tunned eclipse for JVM performance

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I tunned up my Eclipse install in the ini file:

-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810

-showlocation

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

512m

-vmargs

-server

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms40m

-Xss4m

-XX:CompileThreshold=10

-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10

-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70

-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing

-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods

-Xmx684m

Note I am on eclipse 3.6 and using jdk 1.6..

The other thing update to Eclipse 3.6..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "Android Library Update" phase includes network traffic, which is slow. Would your suggested solution reduce the network traffic ?

Comment: I have tried this out but still doesn't seem to make any difference for me.Any luck with you?

Comment: Damned annoying to me also. The above hasnt seemed to help. The only work around I have for the time being is to "never get out of the boat". That is, never quit eclipse or switch workspaces.

Comment: Agree with all - I think this is not an eclipse issue - more an android related one.

Comment: Or just get off 32bit OSes :)..I now the pain will be upgrading soon on my box to a 64bit OS

Comment: How is this different between 32 and 64 bit?