# Eclipse - Android Library Update

Tags: android, eclipse

Related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614752/can-the-android-library-update-phase-somehow-be-sped-up/5513413#5513413), is the Android Library Update step necessary and, if not, can it be removed from the startup and/or build process? A manual update seems like an appropriate option, especially if it improves build times and you already have a previous clean compile.

Comment: If you switch off Build Automatically does that speed up the Lib Load time. That option causes a lot of behind the scenes cleans/builds and refreshes.

Comment: Yes. However, with a fresh install, the loads times are quick. As I modify my 20 or so projects (most of which are closed at any given time), it seems to take longer. If I change the Android build target for a project, that seems to make the build time worse. But I can't find the settings or options for the build or why this would happen. This happens with the start-up and subsequent Auto builds.

Comment: It seems build-times were related to anti-virus and anti-malware settings. I could not reconfigure AVG, so I installed Avast. Microsoft Essentials was also a problem. Having several anti-virus scans on these directories/processes caused slow build times. Now build times are much better. Since the question was related to build times, this seems relevant. Still no info on how to modify or remove the update step...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may not exactly answer your question, but if you do have a lot of projects it will rebuilt all of it when you open eclipse.  what i do myself is i "close" the projects that I'm not working on and I find it more tolerable

Comment: I agree this is not exactly the "right" answer, but this is what I've been doing. So until another answer comes up...

Comment: I don't understand why us devs have to jump through soooo many hoops with Android SDK if its not this issue, its conflicts when updating, if not that, its the emulator HAX not working, if not that it's something else. I've wasted more time and have had to reinstall Eclipse+ADT more than I have other apps. The fact that there is so many SO questions is a testament of what I'm talking about. Please excuse me just a dev tired of trying to fix the Android tools that were given to me to create apps for Android...sigh..

Answer (score 5):

You can disable Android Development Toolkit from General -> Startup and Shutdown.

Comment: If you do this, your android projects wont load properly

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to debug your native code, you could simply not add native support in the first place and just build it on the command line when needed.  Then your eclipse project would simply act as a Java only project and build quickly.

Comment: Also of note, to [remove native support](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.ca/2011/12/removing-native-support-from-android.html)

Comment: Why would you want to remove native support?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with 50 ish projects in my workspace. Not all of them are open at once. Still the 'Android Library Update' would show up every time I needed to update a small thing on every project and really slow me down.

I tried following  but the last one worked like a charm for me.

Obviously, opening only related projects helps too.

Removing `Build Automatically` gets rid of this problem but makes twice more problems. You end up wasting more time manually building the projects. Didn't work for me at all.

Selectively building only the projects that changed helps too.

**But the main thing that completely fixed this problem for me was following**

Go to `Window->Preference->Android->Build` and make sure the third **check box** `Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch.` is **marked on**.