# Eclipse stuck with Android Library Update at 3%

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm at a standstill in Eclipse due to an "Android Library Update" that never finishes. I tried restarting Eclipse, restarting my computer, [deleting the .metadata folder under my Eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766986/android-library-update-eclipse-task-randomly-stuck-my-eclipse-on-start), and several other shots in the dark. Under Window -> Preferences, I also already checked "Skip packaging and dexing (...)"

I have only two projects open: a small demo app and the Google Play Services Library linked to it. So the problem can't be too many projects, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516827/eclipse-android-library-update).

Does anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See the various steps in this post:

[Eclipse hangs at the Android SDK Content Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489141/eclipse-hangs-at-the-android-sdk-content-loader/19037038#19037038)

One of the answers is mine (delete "workbench.xmi") which works for me the best. I find I have to do this every month or so.

Comment: I just closed Eclipse, deleted that XML file, and restarted Eclipse, but came back to the same dreaded update bar. Thanks for the link to that thread, though - I'll look through the other suggestions there.

Comment: Update, in case anyone finds it useful: I just had to reinstall Eclipse and the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, Open **Windows Task Manager** and serach for process named 'aapt.exe' and kill the same. This makes library update will start frome begining and it will continue further.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

Make sure that eclipse is not active. If it is active kill eclipse from the processes tab of the task manager

1. Open %USERPROFILE%/ on Windows or simply ~ on Linux/OS X (You can
   locate this folder from the Desktop)
2. Go to .android folder (This may be a hidden folder)
3. Delete the folder cache which is located inside
   .android folder
4. Delete the file ddms.cfg which is located inside
   .android folder
5. Start Eclipse

I tried the above and it worked for me.
Hope it works for you as well.